# Cross-platform synchronization primitives which allow determining which PID is using them

Tags: c, winapi, posix, ipc

I need to design a wrapper for a process synchronization primitive which acts like a semaphore with let's say limit 1 (so that only one client can have it locked at the same time). If this was the only requirement then I could just use named semaphores. But I'd also like to know, in the scenarios where a client can not lock the primitive, who actually has locked it. The best would be to know the locking process id. I see how I can achieve this on POSIX systems with `semctl` and `GETPID` but Windows does not expose anything like that. I am also aware that I can easily achieve this with files (e.g. opening a known file with shared read and non shared write permissions - when locking the client creates that file and writes it's PID so that the others can read it), but if possible I'd like to use actual OS API primitives instead of filesystem. Is this possible?

Comment: It is strictly forbidden knowledge in Windows, info accessible only to a debugger.  Probably with the root idea that exposing this info is dangerous, users tend to do something icky like terminating a process.  Notable is the SysInternals' Handle utility, it works by dynamically injecting ring 0 code that walks the undocumented handle table.

Comment: You can create a named shared memory block to store the owner pid.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows there is the [Wait Chain Traversal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/using-wct) which allows you to see who has locked what.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out.